# Spread spectrum 400 KHz

Tags: power, design, clock, dc-dc-converter, computer-architecture

I got a 6-phase DC-DC converter. Fsw=400 kHz, synchronization by external clock(CPLD). I need a spread spectrum 400 kHz. What's the best way?
 All chips what I've seen before worked on MHz and above. Is there solution, based on FPGA?

Maybe someone has faced with that problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modulate the 400kHz up and down a little bit. This will spread the spectrum of the noise your 6ph converter produces. This would be a standard approach. If you want this verifying for your precise set-up then circuits are needed.